# Delete rows with a 'LIKE' pattern (not an exact pattern) in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset where I would like to remove all rows that contain data with a certain pattern.

**Data**

```
ID  Date    Stat
AA  Q1.22   ok
CC  Q2.22   yes
CC  Q1.23   ok
CC  Q1.24   no
```

**Desired**

```
ID  Date    Stat
CC  Q1.24   no
```

**Doing**

```
df = df[df["Date"].str.contains(".22|.23") == False]
```

Row are not being deleted, I may have to add a regex.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the code to build your exact dataframe? Because when I try your code from "Doing" everything works fine.

Alternatively you could do:
```df = df[~df["Date"].str.contains(".22|.23")]```

Answer (score 0):

it is very easy. use from regex method.

pandas.Series.str.findall()

pandas.Series.str.find()